# Gatsby navigate returns 404 page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to programmaticaly navigate using gatsby's `navigate()`however, all I'm getting is 404 page although I have the same file in pages folder.

Also, I'm using a functional component.

```
  const navList = [
    { name: 'Turning Forward', path: '/turning-forward' },
    { name: 'Blog', path: '/blog' },
    { name: 'Contact Us', path: '/contact-us' },
    { name: 'About Us', path: '/about-us' }

  ]
      return (
        <header>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Paper className={`${classes.paper} ${classes.paperPreHeader}`}>
              <Link to="/" style={linkStyle}>
                Unique Creation
              </Link>
            </Paper>
          </Grid>
          <div className={navModClass}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Paper className={`${classes.paper} ${classes.paperHeader}`}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                  <nav className='navigation-list-container'>
                    <ul className='navigation-list'>
                      {navList.map((item) => (<li key={item.path}><button onClick={() => navigate(item.path, { replace: true })}>{item.name}</button></li>))}
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </Grid>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </header>
      )
    }
```

[image: application]
[![Pages][2]][2]

Please any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The native approach is using [`Link`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/) component instead of navigate function inside a callback:

```
{navList.map((item) => (<li key={item.path}><Link to={item.path}>{item.name}</Link></li>
```

If you still want to use navigate helper function, import it from Gatsby and try it without the callback;

```
import { navigate } from "gatsby"


{navList.map((item) => (<li key={item.path}><button onClick={navigate(item.path)}>{item.name}</button></li>))}
```